# Copy files without .gitignore?

Tags: git, macos, gitignore

I had a few Javascript projects and I need to copy or move to another machine. And I would like to ignore files which are already in `.gitignore`. Now, when I copy the folder I got git ignored folders and files. But, I want to ignore those when I copy (<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>). How can I configure it?

Comment: Why not just `git clone` the project to a new location?

Comment: @Mureinik internet connection is pretty big problem here :(

Comment: See my answer below - I meant using `git clone` between the two locations you want.

Comment: @Mureinik That's brilliant, I haven't think about it.

Comment: You could use something like `git archive --format=zip`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use git clone:

```
$ git clone machine1:/path/to/project machine2:/target/path
```

Comment: how can you easily transfer the origin remote config?

Answer (score 1):

To remove ignored files from a repository, you can use `git clean`.

```
git clean -nx
```

- `-n` means dry-run; it will cause it to list the files it would delete without actually deleting them.
- `-x` means remove ignored files.

If you also need to remove directories, specify `-d`.

After making sure that what above command prints is what you want to remove, replace `-n` with `-f` to run it for real.

```
git clean -fx
```

**Keep in mind that this will delete files**, and there is no way of getting them back unless you have a backup.

More info at [man git-clean](https://gitirc.eu/git-clean.html).